# Criar paginação exibindo os registros atuais no topo da lista

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados, paginação

Estou criando uma pagina que contém paginação, mas estou com um problema, a paginação funciona perfeito mas trás os registros mais antigos primeiro e eu gostaria que os registros atuais fossem exibidos primeiro, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código que criei como exemplo abaixo:

```
    <?php  
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
        mysql_select_db("paginacao");


    ?>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <th width="60">ID</th>
                <th width="150">Descrição</th>
                <th width="80">Valor</th>
            </tr>

            <?php  

                $limite = 3;
                $sql_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM produtos;");

                $sql_result = ceil(mysql_result($sql_count, 0) / $limite);

                $pg = (isset($_GET["pg"])) ? (int) $_GET["pg"] : 1;

                $start = ($pg - 1) * $limite;

                $sql_produtos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos LIMIT $start, $limite");
                while ($lh = mysql_fetch_array($sql_produtos)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $lh['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo utf8_encode($lh['descricao']); ?></td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $lh['valor'] ?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            <tr>

                <td align="center" colspan="3" >
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="pagination"> 
                            <?php 
                                if ($sql_result > 1 && $pg<=$sql_result) {
                                    for($i=1; $i <= $sql_result; $i++){
                                        echo "<li><a href='?pg=$i'> $i </a></li>";
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <?php echo isset($_GET["pg"]); ?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, o que vai determinar isso é o resultado da sua consulta ao banco. Sendo assim, use um `ORDER BY` com `DESC` para inverter o resultado. Basta escolher qual campo determina quais registros são mais recentes.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$sql_produtos = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                               FROM produtos 
                              ORDER BY meu_campo DESC 
                              LIMIT $start, $limite");
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.